# Excel: Fastest way to find unique values for large amount of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large amount of data (about 1,000,000 rows of data). What is the fastest way to find unique values for one column?

[Edit] I am not sure about how data repeats a lot or there are many unique values. I only want unique. Can remove duplicate values in original set. Or take the unique set and copy to column next to it.

Yes, 1,000,000 rows is a lot, but I cannot use any database to help out.
[/Edit]

I know the Data ribbon, Advanced option. It is slow and seems looping for sometime.

My excel is 2013 version.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean there is a lot of duplicated values in this column and a few unique (non-duplicated), and you want to find only the second ones list? What output form you need - copy to another column, highlight, hide rows with duplicated values, etc.?

Comment: `Data Ribbon -> Remove Duplicates` will be the fastest way.

Comment: Since you have specified the Fastest way to find unique values from large amount of data so that I've suggested you one simple Macro, just check it, is very easy to use, the alternative is Formula !

Comment: Your use of the singular "value" leads to different possible interpretations of your question.  Are you looking to eliminate duplicates from the list, leaving a single copy of every different value, or as Akina suggested, identify the items that already exist only as unique values (or the single such case), and ignore values for which there are duplicates?  BTW, 1,000,000 rows of data will take some time to process in Excel.  If you're dealing with data on that scale, it might make sense to do this in a database.

Comment: @Akina I want to get a list of unique values. This list can be in a new column, or remove duplicates in original list/set.

Answer (score 1):

***The fastest method to find & extract Unique values for Large data range is, MACRO (VBA).***

[image]

*Insert this code as standard Module with the sheet.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetUniqueList()

Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Range("A2:A" & lr)
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i
Range("B2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. In VB Editor click **Tool** menu & hit **References** and check whether
   **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** is checked or not, check it if not.
2. Back to sheet & Run the Macro.
3. It checks Duplicates in column A & output Unique in column B.

*You find the list of unique values in Column B.*

**Note,** adjust cell references in code as needed.